# Aggregate values of grouped SQL results

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a query like the below:

```
SELECT value
    FROM people
    GROUP BY id
```

With `people` table structure like:

```
... | id | value
----------------
... | 1 | 5.43
... | 1 | 4.92
... | 1 | 1.22
... | 2 | 2.11
... | 2 | 1.00
... | 3 | 4.33
... | 4 | 9.12
... | 5 | 4.43
... | 5 | 5.09
... |...| ...
```

This would return a result set like the below:

```
id | value
----------
 1 | 5.43
 2 | 2.11
 3 | 4.33
 4 | 9.12
 5 | 4.43
...| ...
```

It only takes the first `value` per `id`, but I want to aggregate them. eg. the `value` of the grouped `id = 1` would be `3.86`. I'm not sure the SQL for this, or even if it is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just looking for `avg()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean average?

```
SELECT id,avg(value) 
    FROM people
    GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to get an average.

```
SELECT id, avg(value)
 FROM people 
GROUP BY id
```